# Python Turtle/Tkinter Timers Accelerating

Tags: python, tkinter, timer, turtle-graphics

I thought the canonical way to do animation with Python Turtle Graphics was to do something like

```
def animate():
   # move stuff
   ontimer(animate, delay)
```

Looking into the source code for `turtle` this implements `tkinter` `after()` in the background.

Can someone explain why in the program below the animation accelerates and decelerates dramatically when it is left running?

My theory is that since a new `.after()` id is created each time `ontimer()` is called, there are somehow multiple timers in existence which interfere with each other? Or maybe it's just a result of the randomness in the program? Or maybe the short interval between callbacks causes problems?

```
from random import *
from turtle import *
import math

class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, x = 0.0, y = 0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self, other):
        """ Move vector by other (in-place)."""
        self.__iadd__(other)

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Vector):
            self.x += other.x
            self.y += other.y
        else:
            self.x += other
            self.y += other

    def rotate(self, angle):
        """Rotate vector counter-clockwise by angle (in-place)."""
        radians = angle * math.pi / 180.0
        cosine = math.cos(radians)
        sine = math.sin(radians)
        x = self.x
        y = self.y
        self.x = x * cosine - y * sine
        self.y = y * cosine + x * sine

ant = Vector(0, 0)
aim = Vector(2, 0)

def wrap(value):
    "Wrap value around -200 and 200."
    if value > 200:
        value = -200
    elif value < -200:
        value = 200
    return value

def draw():
    "Move ant and draw screen."
    ant.move(aim)
    ant.x = wrap(ant.x)
    ant.y = wrap(ant.y)

    aim.move(random() - 0.5)
    aim.rotate(random() * 10 - 5)

    clear()
    goto(ant.x, ant.y)
    dot(10)

    if running:
        ontimer(draw, 50)

setup(420, 420, 370, 0)
hideturtle()
tracer(False)
up()
running = True
draw()
done()
```

Comment: It should be caused by the randomness.

Comment: Have you run it and seen how it behaves? It looks like more than just the variation caused by random movement.

Comment: Yes, I have.  There is only `draw()` (except the one before `done()`) call itself via `ontimer`, so there should not be the reason of multiple `ontimer` tasks.

Comment: If you look at the ids from `Screen.getcanvas().after(...)`, a new timer is created every time the function calls itself. There is no explicit destruction of each one. I've managed to fix a bug in another program by explicitly destroying the current `.after()` id at the start of the repeating function. Regarding this program though, did it not accelerate beyond the speed you would expect from the random values?

Answer (score 0):

My belief is that your animation accelerates and decelerates because you use `tracer()` but fail to do an explicit `update()`.  The `tracer()` function turns off animation but some turtle operations do an implicit `update()` as a side effect.  Since you didn't do an explicit `update()` you're *only* getting random updates caused by those side effects.

Below I've added an explicit `update()` and simplified the code to make the turtle itself the moving object, rather than *stamping* and *clearing*.  (BTW, if you save the result of `stamp()` you can ask it to clear itself.)

I've also switched from a circle to a turtle cursor image and added in logic to set the heading to the direction of motion:

```
from random import random
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, Vec2D
from math import pi, cos, sin

class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self, other):
        """ Move vector by other (in-place)."""

        self.__iadd__(other)

        self.wrap()

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Vector):
            self.x += other.x
            self.y += other.y
        else:
            self.x += other
            self.y += other

    def rotate(self, degrees):
        """ Rotate vector counter-clockwise by angle (in-place). """

        radians = degrees * pi / 180.0
        cosine = cos(radians)
        sine = sin(radians)

        x = self.x
        y = self.y

        self.x = x * cosine - y * sine
        self.y = y * cosine + x * sine

    def position(self):
        return Vec2D(self.x, self.y)

    def wrap(self):
        """ Wrap value around -200 and 200. """

        x = self.x
        y = self.y

        if x > 200:
            self.x = -200
        elif x < -200:
            self.x = 200

        if y > 200:
            self.y = -200
        elif y < -200:
            self.y = 200

def draw():
    """ Move ant and draw screen. """

    ant.move(aim)

    position = ant.position()
    turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(position))
    turtle.setposition(position)

    screen.update()

    aim.move(random() - 0.5)
    aim.rotate(random() * 10 - 5)

    screen.ontimer(draw, 75)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(420, 420)
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.shapesize(0.5)
turtle.penup()
turtle.showturtle()

ant = Vector(0, 0)
aim = Vector(2, 0)

draw()

screen.mainloop()
```